# Prevent a view from getting outside of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm working with the Google Maps API v2, and I overrided [`getInfoContents()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.html#getInfoContents(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker)) from `InfoWindowAdapter` for having a customized `InfoWindow`. Inside `getInfoContents()`I inflate an xml containing an `ImageView`, and three `TextViews`.

My problem comes when the text that is set inside the `snippet` is larger than the view, then the count TV it's set outside the view. This is illustrated above with some screenshots.

[image] [image]
[image]

Here my xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/categoryIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/count"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/categoryIcon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snippet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Snippet" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#111177"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I change this layout for getting the count TextView inside of the screen, and the snippet in multiline?

I want to always show the count TextView.

UPDATE:
Finally with the answer of Simon Marquis I realized a way to accomplish this. Here the new code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/categoryIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/categoryIcon">

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snippet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Snippeta" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#111177"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this to the LinearLayout:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

The new layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/categoryIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/count"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/categoryIcon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snippet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Snippet" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#111177"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The use of weight inside a RelativeLayout doesn't affecto to the view, so what I have done is create another LinearLayout that contains the other Linear and the count. I update my answer with the solution.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks. @Simon please, do you think you could help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598696/recommended-way-order-to-read-data-from-a-webservice-parse-that-data-and-inse

Answer (score 1):

One solution if you want that the count TextView always appears at right is the following:

- Put the count Text View before the LinearLayout and add
  **android:layout_alignParentRight="true"**
- And add **android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/count"** in the Linear Layout

  ```
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/count"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:background="#00F"
      android:text="Large Text"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/count"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/snippet"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

  </LinearLayout>
  ```

Comment: This will work always that the text is larger than the view, but when it's smaller, the view will have it's maximum size, because the view is alignedParentRight and android uses the top left corner for setting the bounds of the views. So it will have the appearence that width = MATCH_PARENT